# Audio op amps - what do they do to the audio I hear from the speaker?

Tags: arduino, operational-amplifier, amplifier, audio, esp8266

I have a simple DC circuit which outputs audio from a ESP8266 attached via 2 wires and a NPN transistor to a simple speaker. It uses this library : https://github.com/earlephilhower/ESP8266Audio/ to read and playback audio, it works and I hear audio.

My circuit at the audio bit looks similar to this:

```
     2N3904 (NPN)
                            +---------+
                            |         |     +-|
                            | E  B  C |    / S|
                            +-|--|--|-+    | P|
                              |  |  +------+ E|
                              |  |         | A|
ESP8266-GND ------------------+  |  +------+ K| 
                                 |  |      | E|
ESP8266-I2SOUT (Rx) -------------+  |      \ R|
                                    |       +-|
USB 5V -----------------------------+
```

I also have an audio op amp : OPA2134PA. The Datasheet which I have read can be found here: http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/opa2134.pdf

Having read this pdf, and various other google searches I cannot determine, what an Audio Op Amp does? I know an op amp, takes the difference between 2 inputs, and amplifies it.

What does this mean for my circuit and more importantly to the sound I hear from my speaker were I to add the OPA2134PA?

I think my pins would be:

```
1 - Output (negative to speaker?)
2 - Input negative (collector on NPN transistor)
3 - Input positive (USB 5V line . ???)
4 - Negative power supply (??) 
5 - Positive power supply (??)
```

The pins are likely wrong, so in addition to my simpler, what effect does the audio op amp have on my sound playback question, please also help me figure out how to wire in my audio op amp pins correctly.

Comment: The current speaker arrangement produces audio using pulse coding methods, if done well anyway. Sometimes, it is just a simple tone, though. An audio amplifier can usually provide better quality output, but also likely involves different software as well as some thinking about the hardware applied prior to the amplifier input. This is a very different design, though.

Comment: Output current is limited to +/-35mA, so, not much.If you want more volume, you are looking for an audio power amp, not an opamp, like the LM386 (0.25W) or better.

Comment: @jonk what might this design look like then?

BrianDrummond - Ahhh thats helpful , on the volume side. You say current is limited to, are you figuring that based upon the esp8266 specs?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Given the \$5\:\text{V}\$ USB rail, why don't you consider the TDA8551. It's cheap, widely available, provides the maximum possible volume available due to the bridge tied load arrangement it offers, and it includes a very easy to use volume control pin you can operate from the ESP8266, trivially. It is everything you should hope for in something like this. You will still need a way to generate the input audio signal. (Which can use a digital PWM I/O feeding a passive low-pass filter, I think.) Or find a class-D IC and go that way.

Comment: Can it be powered by an ESP8266, driving a DAC through I2S, then onto the TDA8551?

Comment: It looks good but seems to be Mono....any suggested stereo alternatives?

Comment: @jonk ideas for my above comments?

Comment: @RenegadeAndy Yes, anything that will generate an analog signal fast enough for audio and be able to provide a very modest current compliance for the TDA8551 will work just fine. The TDA8551 is a part used in cheap "PC speakers" all the time. The ones with the "volume up" and "volume down" push buttons on them. It's an all-in-one chip for those things. I2C can drive DACs. That said, there may need to be a modest "middle man" circuit that mediates between a DAC and the TDA8551. But it would be easy to design. Perhaps another question you ask here, with specifics provided?

Comment: -1 for ASCII art.  There is no excuse today.  There is a built-in schematic editor, and you can paste images exported from just about any schematic capture software.  Note that your ASCII art doesn't show the transistor properly, instead has to label E, B, and C.  That's a wiring diagram, not a schematic.  That's not how its done here.  Closing since I'm not going to read past seeing the ASCII art wiring diagram.

Comment: @OlinLathrop please, this is not your personal fiefdom, this is a group consensus site.  If you close unilaterally you are working outside your brief, if you are "voting" to close then say so and not pretend you will "close" when speaking accurately.  The occasional ASCII art is retro, refreshing and quite adequate for two components, no further information would be gained from a visit to the schematic editor.